# How to parse "April 2023" to time.Time object in golang

Tags: datetime, go, object, parsing

i am unable to parse datestring like `April 2023` to time.Time object to compare datetime object in golang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t, err := time.Parse("January 2006", "April 2023")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
    // 2023-04-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
}
```